ReferenceError: 'BigInt' doesn't exist (Hermes); Invariant Violation: AppRegistry module not registered (Hermes)
**I was working on a React Native project using version 0.64.1. I attempted to upgrade to version 0.74.0 but was unsuccessful. As a result, I decided to revert to the original version, 0.64.1, and stashed all the changes.
However, after stashing the changes and running the usual commands to start the project, I encountered errors.
**
Error :
**Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
 ERROR  ReferenceError: Property 'BigInt' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes**


NODE : 14.15.4
NPM : 6.14.10
JDK : 11.0.23
To resolve this, I tried the following steps:
-Deleted the project and cloned a fresh copy, but the same error occurred.
-Deleted the project and Android Studio, then cloned a fresh copy, but the same error persisted.
-Ran various commands to resolve the error, but none were successful.
-Reset my laptop and set up everything again from scratch, but I still encountered the same error.

Did you delete all node_modules and yarn.lock file then run fresh npm install?

yes brother, I have tried many times but didn't work. then I copied node modules from senior's laptop and use it. then it working fine.
When I do npm install then same error getting. don't why ??

Try deleting your react native globally and installing only the exact version as your package.json

Thank you so much brother, I checked react native version globally it is showing latest one 0.74.2 which I don't need. I tried to uninstall that version multiple time but it didn't uninstall.
commands Which I have used : ---
npm uninstall -g react-native@0.74.2
npm cache clean --force
npm view react-native version

Since you have react native installed globally, I would suggest you to delete using this method:

Run this command npm list -g
Goto the path
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm)
Delete all the related files to
your package
Goto node_modules find and delete the package

Once it is uninstalled, install react-native locally within your working directory. Using
npm install react-native@<your_version>


Step 1 :  npm list -g  ..................
C:\Program Files\nodejs
-- npm@6.14.10   +-- abbrev@1.1.1   +-- ajv@5.5.2   | +-- co@4.6.0   | +-- fast-deep-equal@1.1.0   | +-- fast-json-stable-stringify@2.0.0   | -- json-schema-traverse@0.3.1
+-- ansicolors@0.3.2
+-- ansistyles@0.1.3
+-- aproba@2.0.0
+-- archy@1.0.0
.....soon
................  step 2  and Step 3 : Goto the path (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm)  delete npm folder content.
................ step 4 : Goto node_modules find means ?   I need to delete that folder ?

yes delete that folder

brother, error is still there. is there any way to connect you ?
you can give me your linkedin Id. I really appreciate that.

Error is not yet resolve.
